# Creating a gallery of images stored in AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I have an S3 bucket with a couple of sub-directories (keys) each containing a number of images. I want to be able to display these images in a gallery-like way on a website.

The images are public, so yes, I know that I can use the public url, but the problem is that I won't know the names of the files, as they are being uploaded in real-time by users, using a separate pipeline.

I have looked through [this API Gateway tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html), but that only seems to be able to give me binary encodings of the images (?). I don't have much front-end experience, but I don't believe that's what I need? I really just need a list of all the public urls (or just filenames and I can create the url myself), and I would like to get this via a REST API call.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, that would be great!

Comment: The second link at the top of that tutorial you linked gives you the list of all the files: "Expose GET on a Folder resource to view a list of all of the objects in an Amazon S3 bucket." http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Mark B suggests would probably also work, but what I ended up doing was the following:

I created an AWS Lambda which used the S3 SDK and did what I wanted to do, and I made sure that the return format followed [the correct output format of a Lambda function for proxy integration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format).

Then I created an API Gateway with integration type == Lambda function, and Lambda Proxy Integration turned on. This allows me to access query parameters in the API call inside of the Lambda, in the "event" of the handler function.